# Run as Different User Include Password - Bat

Tags: batch-file

I currently have a Batch file that opens Power BI Desktop but as different User, but when I run this .bat file it prompts me to type in my password, is it possible to include the password with in the script so I do not have to type this in?

This is the current script I have within my .bat file

```
runas /user:joe_bloggs@mcisrd.com "C:\Program Files\Microsoft Power BI Desktop\bin\PBIDesktop.exe"
```

Thanks

Comment: Please open a [command prompt](https://www.howtogeek.com/235101/) window, run `runas /?` and read the output usage help and you can answer the question by yourself. There can be also configured a scheduled task with the action to run `"C:\Program Files\Microsoft Power BI Desktop\bin\PBIDesktop.exe"` using the account `joe_bloggs@mcisrd.com`. In this case the credentials (user name and password) must be entered only once on saving the scheduled task.

Answer (score 1):

Another option would be this:

```
echo.[PASSWORD]>"%TEMP%\pass.txt"
runas /user:joe_bloggs@mcisrd.com "C:\Program Files\Microsoft Power BI Desktop\bin\PBIDesktop.exe" < "%TEMP%\pass.txt"
del "%TEMP%\pass.txt"
```

(replacing [PASSWORD] with the actual password.)